# Delayed drawing of MKPolylines in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mapkit

I have code that draws MKPolylines on a map and until the release of iOS6 everything was working fine. In iOS6 the drawing of the polylines is delayed from a couple of seconds up to 30-40 seconds based on the number of coordinates in the array. This isn't the case in iOS5. I can see the same problem in the different versions of the simulators.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;


    MKPolylineView *polylineView;
    polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        polylineView.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        polylineView.lineWidth = 12;
    }
}
```

I add the overlay in viewDidAppear but I have also tried to add it in viewWillAppear with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem.

I fetched the data that sent a callback with it back. When I was adding the overlay I was adding it from the wrong thread and this caused the problem.

So from this:

```
// add the overlay to the map
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

To this helped:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     // add the overlay to the map
     [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
 });
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted if this solved your problem. Marking an answer as accepted helps the community, gives you reputation, and improves Stack Overflow. To do so, click on the grey / white √ symbol next to your answer - accepting the answer will turn the √ green.